# select child at beginning of function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I can't appear to select the child form of a div I have for some reason.

For the matter, I am trying to find a way that I can have a function select the child form of a div since I have it changing for a toggling function at my site.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#soundToggle, #soundOffForm").submit(function(event){
                        /*var r = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
                        r.open("POST", "sessionsetter.php", true);
                        r.onreadystatechange = function () {
                            if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return; 
                            console.log(r.responseText);
                        };
                        r.send("a=1&b=2&c=3");*/
                        alert("post");
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "sessionsetter.php",
                            data: {
                                sound : '0',
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                //alert("Sound toggled successfully: " + data);
                                $('#soundToggle').load(location.href + " #soundOnForm");

                            },
                            error: function(data) {
                                alert("Error in processing request: " + data);
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    $("#soundToggle, #soundOnForm").submit(function(event){
                        event.preventDefault();

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "sessionsetter.php",
                            data: {
                                sound : '1',
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                //alert("Sound toggled successfully: " + data);
                                $('#soundToggle').load(location.href + " #soundOffForm");
                            },
                            error: function(data) {
                                alert("Error in processing request: " + data);

                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
```

Anyone have any suggestions on how I can make this a possibility? Thanks. When I don't select the child of a form, the handler is destroyed as I replace the form in my DOM.

Comment: `$("#soundToggle...").submit()` is called 2 times. The first `#soundToggle` element appears 2 times. So the 2nd function is the only one called.

Comment: I'm sure that the problem is that you use semicolon `,` in the $(), there is no need.

Comment: I have tried it without the commas. It doesn't work. I've also tried $(document).on('submit', '#soundOffForm', function(event)... etc. and they don't work either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The jquery binding will be lost if the Dom is reconstructed after page loads, you may want to use this:
Assumption here is #soundToggle is the div that contains form

```
$("#soundToggle, #soundToggle form").submit(function(event){
    if($("#soundToggle form").attr('id') == "soundOnForm"){
    //do on functionality
    } else if($("#soundToggle form").attr('id') == "soundOffForm"){
    //do off functionality
   }    
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the forms change, and that's why they have their IDs inside the div. Anyway I can select those? Is it just like $("#soundToggle, #soundToggle #soundOffForm") or something like that?

Comment: Note my changes above, "$("#soundToggle, #soundToggle form").submit(function(event){" - this means, it selects whatever form inside the div.

Comment: Yes, but the forms I'm submitted have their different corresponding functions. I don't want both of their corresponding functions to post simultaneously. One form inside the div is supposed to turn the sound on. Another form that replaces inside the div is the toggle to turn the sound off.